# 2 holes on my tallit katana am I fulfilling the mitzva?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, ashkenazi, tallit-katan

I recently bought a tallit katan but realized the tzitzit are tied over 2 holes instead of the usual 1 hole I'm used to is this just another way of tying? I'm Ashkenazi am I fulfilling the mitzva?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gabriel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!